# Do I have to compile to JavaScript?

Tags: dart

imagine you wanna build a web project for the public without any JavaScript dependencies, because you just love Dart. Do I have to compile Dart to JavaScript no matter what or is it possible to run Dart VM on server side with some nginx config.

Answer (score 2):

If you have server-side code in Dart, you can run it on the server using the Dart VM - no need to compile to JS here.
Using nginx with server-side Dart might have advantages for some use cases but it is by no means necessary.

For code that is supposed to run in the browser, you need to compile to JS first.

Answer (score 0):

Dart is deployable everywhere, check [deployment diagram](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/bbad899dd324113ef3d766be7049d3f0675151b6/68747470733a2f2f672e67726176697a6f2e636f6d2f736f757263652f7376673f68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6461666573696d6f6e656b2f646172742d706c6174666f726d2d6469616772616d732f6d61737465722f72756e2d616e642d6465706c6f792e70756d6c) showing where it runs inside Dart VM and where it runs compiled.